# Checkout status icon for folders TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Previously i used VisualSVN and in VisualSVN when i checkout some file appeared red checkout icon against that file and against folder in which the file was. But in TFS red checkout icon appears only against checkout file. Does TFS provide such functionality? Thanks

Comment: No. It makes no sense for the folder to be marked as checked out if you only checked out a few files... unless you checked out the folder itself(and everything underneath it). SVN is bad at misleading users...

Comment: Confirming the no. One could build an addin to do that if you'd want to :).